# Get Picture Messages To C++ program

Tags: android, iphone, c++, windows

I'm currently thinking of setting up a picture message import project. Something like this:

**Client Mobile Device** [picture message] -> our **Server Device**
**Server Device** [picture && number -> **Server Computer**

However I don't know if there's a possible way to do this. I could set up a google voice account and use something like [this](http://github.com/justquick/python-googlevoice/) in order to retrieve messages, however this doesn't allow picture messages...

So I was thinking of perhaps making an android or iPhone application to redirect picture messages. Though I don't know if this is possible. If it is, how would I go about gathering the messages? The networking is simple enough, however I'm not familiar with the android system, nor the message system of the iPhone.

On the other hand, I could make a simple email server to receive messages from the cell phone provider's email system.

Is any of the above viable? The image as well as the origin number are both needed.

Comment: [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-sms/) does nearly what I want, however instead of going to an email, I need to send the data to a server program...

Comment: The program you linked should work, actually. You can set up a gmail account to forward to any other email address. Just point it at an email address on your server, run the incoming mail through procmail or something like it, and you can store the pictures however you like.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you for procmail- but what about pictures? Google voice doesn't allow pictures does it?

Comment: =/ dang, I can't find any viable solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think this is possible. I'm not sure how it works but I'll do my best.

First you have to be notified when an SMS is received by listening to SMS_RECEIVED events. [BroadcastReceiver + SMS_RECEIVED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973071/broadcastreceiver-sms-received)

Second, you have to read the SMS attachment as explained here: [Get attachment from unread MMS messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115939/get-attachment-from-unread-mms-messages)

Does this help?

Comment: That's what I need mate- exactly what I need. Thank you- have some reputation.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a typical client/server application actually, except the commands sent to the server contain binary data.

There are many ways to do this, and many protocols you can use. Email (gmail) is just one example.

What I would do is use HTTP to post binary messages to your web server. This is cool because it manages authentication, data transfer, etc, are all available.

Here's a short example: [Secure HTTP Post in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253061/secure-http-post-in-android)
Just add authentication on top of that and you're in business!

You would have to do some web server development too.

I hope this helps.

Emmanuel

Comment: The problem in this case is not with the communication between the server and the android, I have absolutely no problem with that, I've been doing networking for years. However the problem in this case is getting a received picture message from the android system without user interaction to the server. Including the origin number.

Comment: Ok in that case, you just want to know how to intercept incoming messages and obtain the sender and attachment?

Comment: Certainly, as well as having access to, and rights to send, the associated data. That would be perfect.

Comment: @ultifinitus Sorry, I've never had to do this so I just don't know. :-( I bet you can read the SMS attachments but I don't know how.

Comment: No worries mate- I'll do more research